# How to reset date after click automatically

Tags: html, angular, datetime

I have implemented two dropdown selection which API data to generate report in Angular. For the report generation there're three types of date categories: Daily, Monthly and Yearly. But I got problem when changing to the different option in dropdown date picker date is not change itself.
Example : if I select daily report in dropdown and select date it generate report. But if I select another option date is same as previous one. I need to clear data on one selection. I need a good suggestion for this. I use md-datepicker.

Here's my HTML

**Component.html**

```
<form>
  <div class="row form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-xl-4 col-md-4">
      <label class="center">Report Category</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-xl-4 col-md-4">
      <select id="names" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectReportCategoryName" name="name" (ngModelChange)="getReportType($event);">
        <option value="undefined" disabled selected>--Select Report Category--</option>
        <option *ngFor="let rct of reportCategoryTypes" [value]="rct">{{ rct }}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-xl-4 col-md-4">
      <label class="center">Report Types</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-xl-4 col-md-4">
      <select id="names" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectReportType" name="id" (ngModelChange)="selectedDateType($event)">
        <option value="undefined" [selected]="isSelected">--Select Report Type--</option>
        <option *ngFor="let rt of reportsTypes" [value]="rt.textId">{{ rt.name }}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr class="boder" />
  <md-radio-group>
    <div class="form-group">
      <!-- Radio Button 1 -->
      <div class="row" *ngIf="isDate">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-xl-6 col-md-6 text-center">
          <label> Date: </label>
          <md-input-container class="marginleft15">
            <input mdInput [mdDatepicker]="frompicker" [(ngModel)]="date" readonly name="date" [max]="maxFromDate" (change)="onDateChange($event)" />
            <button mdSuffix [mdDatepickerToggle]="frompicker"></button>
          </md-input-container>
          <md-datepicker #frompicker></md-datepicker>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Radio Button 2 -->
      <div class="row" *ngIf="isMonth">
        <div class="col-lg-9 col-xl-9 col-md-9 row">
          <div class="col-lg-2 col-xl-2 col-md-2" style="margin-top: 10px">
            <label> Month: </label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-xl-4 col-md-4">
            <app-month-dropdown (change)="onMonthChange($event.target.value)" class="marginleft15 dropdown-inline"></app-month-dropdown>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-2 col-xl-2 col-md-2" style="margin-top: 10px">
            <label> Year: </label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-xl-4 col-md-4">
            <app-year-dropdown (change)="onYearChange($event.target.value)" class="marginleft15 dropdown-inline"></app-year-dropdown>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Radio Button 3 -->
      <div class="row" *ngIf="isYear">
        <div class="col-lg-9 col-xl-9 col-md-9 row">
          <div class="col-lg-2 col-xl-2 col-md-2" style="margin-top: 10px">
            <label> Year : </label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-xl-4 col-md-4">
            <app-year-dropdown (change)="onYearChange($event.target.value)" class="marginleft15 dropdown-inline"></app-year-dropdown>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </md-radio-group>
  <div class="row form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-xl-4 col-md-4">
      <label class="center"> </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-xl-3 col-md-3">
      <label class="center"> </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-5 col-xl-5 col-md-5">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-info animate-element mr-5" id="btn" data-animation-class="fadeInRightBig" (click)="export()">
        Generate Report
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

**component.ts**

```
enum ReportsType {
  Monthly = 1,
  Yearly = 2,
  Daily = 3,
}

class PowerMeterReport {
  Date: string;
  DataRangeType: string;
  EndDate: string;
  IsGroup: boolean;
  Month: number;
  ReportType: string;
  ReportCategory: number;
  StartDate: string;
  TagList = [];
  Year: number;
}

@Component({
  selector: "app-power-meter-reports",
  templateUrl: "./power-meter-reports.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./power-meter-reports.component.scss"],
})
export class PowerMeterReportsComponent implements OnInit {
 
 
 
  public powerMeterReport: PowerMeterReport = new PowerMeterReport();

  fromdate: any;
  todate: any;
  tagList = [];
  serviceType: string;
  building: string;
  floor: string;
  location: string;
  selectAll = false;
  selectedTags: any;
  optionsChecked = [];
  powerservices: any[];
  powersubservices: any[];
  powerbuildings: any[];
  powerfloors: any[];
  dataSourceSubscriber: any;
  powerlocations: any[];
  minToDate = new Date(2000, 1, 1);
  maxToDate = new Date();
  maxFromDate = new Date();
  tempTagList = [];
  divHidden: boolean;
  mainDivHidden: boolean;
  show: boolean;
  public dataSource: any;
  public chartType: string;
  chartId: number;
  public data: any;
  reportDivHidden: boolean;
  hourlyFilterDivHidden: boolean;
  dailyFilterDivHidden: boolean;
  monthlyFilterDivHidden: boolean;
  yearlyFilterDivHidden: boolean;
  customFilterDivHidden: boolean;
  hrsdate: any;
  date: Date;
  month: number;
  year: number;
  SelectedType: string;
  reportType: string;
  apiCallDateMonth: number;
  apiCallDateYear: number;
  apiCallDate = new Date();
  subService: string;
  showDateRange: string;
  dateRangeType: string;
  indexes: Array<number> = [];
  dataSources = [];
  IsGroup: boolean;
  chartIds = [];
  chartDivIds = [];
  genarateBtnDivHidden: boolean;
  columnName: string;

  //DROPDOWN PROPERTIES
  reportCategoryTypes: string;
  reportCategoryPrint: string;
  reportsTypes: any;
  ShowReportType: string;
  showReportTypes: string;
  showTheDateRageType: string;
  DownloadFileName: string;
  fileName: string;

  success: boolean = false;

  constructor(
    private toastr: ToastrService,
    private _powerservice: PowerReportService,
    private _SubscriberService: DynamicReportsService,
    private _service: DynamicReportsService,
    private excelService: ExcelService,
    private spinnerService: Ng4LoadingSpinnerService
  ) {
    this.getPowerMeterServices();
    this.getPowerMeterSubServices();
    this.getPowerMeterBuildings();
    this.getPowerMeterFloors();
    this.getPowerMeterLocations();
    //this.getCategoryList();

    setInterval(() => {}, 1000);
  }

  updateCheck() {
    if (this.selectAll === true) {
      this.tagList.map((tag) => {
        tag.checked = true;
      });
    } else {
      this.tagList.map((tag) => {
        tag.checked = false;
      });
    }
  }

  ngOnChanges() {
    console.log();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.chartType = "mscolumn2d";
    // this.getData();

    let date: any = new Date();
    // this.fromdate=date;
    // this.fromdate.setFullYear(date.getFullYear(),date.getMonth(),date.getDate());
    this.date = date;
    // this.date.setFullYear(date.getDate());
    this.serviceType = "All";
    this.building = "All";
    this.floor = "All";
    this.location = "All";
    this.subService = "All";
    this.divHidden = true;
    this.mainDivHidden = false;
    this.show = true;
    this.reportDivHidden = true;
    this.hourlyFilterDivHidden = true;
    this.dailyFilterDivHidden = true;
    this.monthlyFilterDivHidden = true;
    this.yearlyFilterDivHidden = true;
    this.customFilterDivHidden = true;
    $(".animate-element").click(function () {
      $("#animation-object").removeClass();
      var animation_class = $(this).data("animation-class");
      $("#animation-object").addClass("animated " + animation_class);
    });

    $(".main-animate-element").click(function () {
      $("#main-animation-object").removeClass();
      var animation_class = $(this).data("animation-class");
      $("#main-animation-object").addClass("animated " + animation_class);
    });
    this.todate = date;
    this.hrsdate = date;
    var today = new Date();
    this.month = today.getMonth() + 1;
    this.year = today.getFullYear();
    this.genarateBtnDivHidden = true;
    //  this._SubscriberService.currentMessage.subscribe(message => this.dataSourceSubscriber = message);

    //---------------------------------- DTTB only---------------------------------------
    // this.reportType ="Energy"
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //DropDown Report Categorty Type
    this._powerservice.getCategoryType().subscribe((data) => {
      this.reportCategoryTypes = data;
    });
  }



  //DropDown Report Type
  getReportType(serviceTypes: any) {
    this._powerservice.getReportType(serviceTypes).subscribe((data) => {
      this.reportsTypes = data;
    });
    this.serviceType = serviceTypes;
  }

  //Show date type on
  isDate: boolean = false;
  isMonth: boolean = false;
  isYear: boolean = false;

  selectedDateType(reportsType: string) {
    //this.isShown = false;

    //get Category types for execl file name
    this.isDate = false;
    this.isMonth = false;
    this.isYear = false;
    if (reportsType == "daily") {
      this.isDate = true;
      this.showReportTypes = reportsType;
      this.showTheDateRageType = reportsType;
      this.fileName = ConfigService.config.powerMeterReportDownloadNameOne;
    } else if (reportsType == "monthly") {
      this.isMonth = true;
      this.showReportTypes = reportsType;
      this.showTheDateRageType = reportsType;
      this.fileName = ConfigService.config.powerMeterReportDownloadNameTwo;
    } else if (reportsType == "yearly") {
      this.isYear = true;
      this.showReportTypes = reportsType;
      this.showTheDateRageType = reportsType;
      this.fileName = ConfigService.config.powerMeterReportDownloadNameThree;
    }
  }



  getPowerMeterServices(): any {
    this._powerservice.getPowerMeterFilterDataToReport("1").subscribe(
      (res) => {
        this.powerservices = res;
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }
  getPowerMeterSubServices(): any {
    this._powerservice.getPowerMeterFilterDataToReport("sub").subscribe(
      (res) => {
        this.powersubservices = res;
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }
  getPowerMeterBuildings() {
    this._powerservice.getPowerMeterFilterDataToReport("2").subscribe(
      (res) => {
        this.powerbuildings = res;
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }

  getPowerMeterFloors() {
    this._powerservice.getPowerMeterFilterDataToReport("3").subscribe(
      (res) => {
        this.powerfloors = res;
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }

  getPowerMeterLocations() {
    this._powerservice.getPowerMeterFilterDataToReport("4").subscribe(
      (res) => {
        this.powerlocations = res;
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }

  LoadFilteredTags() {
    // this.analyseRadioChangeOnReportShow();
    // if (this.divHidden) {
    //   this.divHidden = false;
    // }
    const loadTags = {
      Service: this.serviceType,
      Building: this.building,
      Floor: this.floor,
      Location: this.location,
      SubService: this.subService,
      ReportType: this.reportType,
    };

    this._powerservice.getRelatedTags(loadTags).subscribe(
      (res) => {
        (this.tempTagList = []),
          (this.tagList = []),
          (this.tempTagList = res),
          this.tempTagList.forEach((element) => {
            this.genarateBtnDivHidden = false;
            this.tagList.push({ name: element, checked: false });
          });
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }

  setSubscriber(data: any) {
    this._SubscriberService.changeMessage(data);
  }
  setToDate() {
    this.minToDate = this.fromdate;
    this.maxToDate = new Date();
  }
  //#region Reporting part
  getData() {
    this.dataSource = {
      chart: {
        caption: "Power Meter Report",
        xAxisName: "Power Meter",
        yAxisName: "Value (kWh)",
        theme: "fusion",
        bgColor: "#292a2c",
        bgAlpha: "100",
        canvasBgColor: "#292a2c",
        borderThickness: "0",
        lineColor: "#00ccff",
        showAlternateHGridColor: "0",
        valueFontColor: "#ffffff",
        anchorRadius: "2",
        baseFontColor: "#ffffff",
        labelFontColor: "#ffffff",
        showLegend: "1",
        legendBgColor: "#292a2c",
        toolTipBgColor: "#000000",
        plotFillAlpha: "80",
        divLineIsDashed: "1",
        divLineDashLen: "1",
        divLineGapLen: "1",
        usePlotGradientColor: "0",
        exportEnabled: "1",
      },
      categories: [
        {
          category: [
            {
              label: "January",
            },
            {
              label: "Februery",
            },
            {
              label: "March",
            },
            {
              label: "April",
            },
            {
              label: "May",
            },
            {
              label: "June",
            },
            {
              label: "July",
            },
            {
              label: "August",
            },
            {
              label: "September",
            },
            {
              label: "October",
            },
            {
              label: "November",
            },
            {
              label: "December",
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
      dataset: [
        {
          seriesname: "MDB-1",
          color: "#6898f6",
          data: [
            {
              value: "",
            },
            {
              value: "",
            },
            {
              value: "",
            },
            {
              value: "",
            },
            {
              value: "",
            },
            {
              value: "",
            },
            {
              value: "",
            },
            {
              value: "",
            },
            {
              value: "",
            },
            {
              value: "",
            },
            {
              value: "9500",
            },
            {
              value: "",
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          seriesname: "MDB-2",
          color: " #00c6ff",
          data: [
            {
              value: "",
            },
            {
              value: "",
            },
            {
              value: "",
            },
            {
              value: "",
            },
            {
              value: "",
            },
            {
              value: "",
            },
            {
              value: "",
            },
            {
              value: "",
            },
            {
              value: "",
            },
            {
              value: "",
            },
            {
              value: "10500",
            },
            {
              value: "",
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          seriesname: "MDB-3",
          color: "#35ffff",
          data: [
            {
              value: "",
            },
            {
              value: "",
            },
            {
              value: "",
            },
            {
              value: "",
            },
            {
              value: "",
            },
            {
              value: "",
            },
            {
              value: "",
            },
            {
              value: "",
            },
            {
              value: "",
            },
            {
              value: "",
            },
            {
              value: "15235",
            },
            {
              value: "",
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          seriesname: "MDB-1 + MDB-2 + MDB-3",
          color: "#a7ff96",
          data: [
            {
              value: "",
            },
            {
              value: "",
            },
            {
              value: "",
            },
            {
              value: "",
            },
            {
              value: "",
            },
            {
              value: "",
            },
            {
              value: "",
            },
            {
              value: "",
            },
            {
              value: "",
            },
            {
              value: "",
            },
            {
              value: "51800",
            },
            {
              value: "",
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    };
  }
  getChartData(): any {
    this._service.getChartData(this.chartId).subscribe(
      (res) => {
        this.dataSource = res;
        console.log(res);
        this.chartType = this.chartType;
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }
  getReportData(): any {
    this._service.getReportData(this.chartId).subscribe(
      (res) => {
        this.dataSource = res;
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }
  exportAsXLSX() {
    this.excelService.exportAsExcelFile(this.data, "Dynamic Reports");
  }


  onDateChange(date: Date) {
    this.date = date;
  }

  onMonthChange(month: number) {
    this.month = month;
  }
  onYearChange(year: number) {
    this.year = year;
  }



  back() {
    window.location.reload();
  }
  downloadImages() {
    this.spinnerService.show();
    for (var i = 0; i < this.chartIds.length; i++) {
      FusionCharts.items[this.chartIds[i]].exportChart({
        exportFormat: "jpg",
        exportFileName: this.chartIds[i],
        exportAction: "download-save",
        // "exportMode":"server",
        //  "exportAtClientSide":0,
      });
    }
  }



  export() {
    let startDate: Date;
    let endDate: Date;
    if (this.showReportTypes == "daily") {
      startDate = this.date;
      //let s = new Date('en-US').transform(startDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
      endDate = new Date(
        this.date.getFullYear(),
        this.date.getMonth(),
        this.date.getDate() + 1
      );
      this.ShowReportType = ReportsType.Daily.toString();
    } else if (this.showReportTypes == "monthly") {
      startDate = new Date(this.year, this.month - 1, 1);
      endDate = new Date(this.year, this.month, 1);
      this.ShowReportType = ReportsType.Monthly.toString();
    } else {
      startDate = new Date(this.year, 0, 1);
      endDate = new Date(startDate.getFullYear() + 1, 0, 1);
      this.ShowReportType = ReportsType.Yearly.toString();
    }

    const info = {
      StartDate: new DatePipe("en-US").transform(startDate, "yyyy-MM-dd"),
      EndDate: new DatePipe("en-US").transform(endDate, "yyyy-MM-dd"),
      TagList: [],
      Date: this.date,
      Month: this.month,
      Year: this.year,
      DateRangeType: this.showTheDateRageType,
      ReportType: this.ShowReportType,
      ReportCategory: this.serviceType,
      IsGroup: true,
    };
    console.log(info);
    console.log("new");

    let now = new Date();
    let transformDate = new DatePipe("en-US").transform(now,"dd:MMM:yyyy hh-mm-ss"
    );

    this._powerservice.generateReport(info).subscribe(
      (data) => {
        let newBlob = new Blob([data], {
          type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;",
        });

        if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
          window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(newBlob);
          return;
        }

        let dataS = window.URL.createObjectURL(newBlob);
        let link = document.createElement("a");
        link.href = dataS;
        link.download =  this.serviceType + "-" + this.fileName + " -T-" + transformDate;
        link.click();
        setTimeout(() => {
          window.URL.revokeObjectURL(data);
        }, 100);

        this.toastr.success("Report Genarate Successfully", "", {
          positionClass: "toast-top-full-width",
        });
        this.spinnerService.hide();
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
        this.toastr.error("Error in Report Genarate", "", {
          positionClass: "toast-top-full-width",
        });
        this.spinnerService.hide();
      }
    );
  }
  export_chart() {
    this.downloadImages();
    setTimeout(() => this.export(), 10000);
  }


}
```

Comment: can you also share your TS code? It is difficult to determine the flow without the TS code?

Comment: I include the full code for your reference. Take a look at it

Comment: this has a huge number of properties in this component, I will not go to them and try to simplify but I would suggest to not use jquery in angular it will just make it complex and unpredictable. Let me see how you can fix your issue.

Comment: Actually I include all the code to get idea of it.  I will really appreciate your effort to figure it out the issue I'm having right now. Except component.ts would you able to suggest something with location.reload() in html view datepicker div?

Comment: I tried it before it load all the page. But consider with <div class="row form-group"> tag would you able to suggest something? I'm little bit messed with up how to cope it. Thanks lot Sir!

Comment: give me a while I am into something I will have a full scan of your code and try to help :)

Comment: @Tad_Williams_FE You are binding the datePicker with date field. Just simply set it to empty whenever your dropdown value changes on onChange event handler.

Comment: @VimalPatel That would be helpful Thanks lot

Comment: @Tad_Williams_FE as suggested by @VimalPatel, I think you just need to change the date whenever there is any change in the dropdown, change in this method `selectedDateType`